# app crashed when popoverPresentationController and keyboard dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController`, which add a `UITableView`, a `UISearchController`. I present this `ViewController` as `UIModalPresentationPopover` style.If i only dismiss the `ViewController`, that's no problem.But when searching text and keyboard showed, then dismiss the `ViewController`, it crashed! It don't crash when i tap the area outside the popover view.

```
[Self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];//dismiss
```

it'll crash when dismiss like this pic below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUNEh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmTFM.png)

```
  Thread 1 > 19 UIApplicationMain
UIKit`UIApplicationMain:
0x11119d549 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
0x11119d54a <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x11119d54d <+4>:   pushq  %r15
0x11119d54f <+6>:   pushq  %r14
0x11119d551 <+8>:   pushq  %r13
0x11119d553 <+10>:  pushq  %r12
0x11119d555 <+12>:  pushq  %rbx
0x11119d556 <+13>:  pushq  %rax
0x11119d557 <+14>:  movq   %rcx, %rbx
0x11119d55a <+17>:  movq   %rsi, -0x30(%rbp)
0x11119d55e <+21>:  movl   %edi, %r12d
0x11119d561 <+24>:  movq   0x115d090(%rip), %r13     ; (void *)0x0000000114a1dc50: objc_retain
0x11119d568 <+31>:  movq   %rdx, %rdi
0x11119d56b <+34>:  callq  *%r13
0x11119d56e <+37>:  movq   %rax, %r14
0x11119d571 <+40>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x11119d574 <+43>:  callq  *%r13
0x11119d577 <+46>:  movq   %rax, %r15
0x11119d57a <+49>:  leaq   0x158700b(%rip), %r13     ; _UIApplicationLinkedOnVersion
0x11119d581 <+56>:  movl   (%r13), %eax
0x11119d585 <+60>:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x11119d587 <+62>:  jne    0x11119d597               ; <+78>
0x11119d589 <+64>:  cmpq   $-0x1, 0x157fc7f(%rip)    ; WebKitSetIsClassic + 7
0x11119d591 <+72>:  jne    0x11119d60a               ; <+193>
0x11119d593 <+74>:  movl   (%r13), %eax
0x11119d597 <+78>:  cmpl   $0x20100, %eax            ; imm = 0x20100 
0x11119d59c <+83>:  jb     0x11119d5c2               ; <+121>
0x11119d59e <+85>:  callq  0x11200f0a8               ; symbol stub for: objc_autoreleasePoolPush
0x11119d5a3 <+90>:  movq   %rax, %r13
0x11119d5a6 <+93>:  movl   %r12d, %edi
0x11119d5a9 <+96>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rsi
0x11119d5ad <+100>: movq   %r14, %rdx
0x11119d5b0 <+103>: movq   %r15, %rcx
0x11119d5b3 <+106>: callq  0x11119d622               ; _UIApplicationMainPreparations
0x11119d5b8 <+111>: movq   %r13, %rdi
0x11119d5bb <+114>: callq  0x11200f0a2               ; symbol stub for: objc_autoreleasePoolPop
0x11119d5c0 <+119>: jmp    0x11119d5d4               ; <+139>
0x11119d5c2 <+121>: movl   %r12d, %edi
0x11119d5c5 <+124>: movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rsi
0x11119d5c9 <+128>: movq   %r14, %rdx
0x11119d5cc <+131>: movq   %r15, %rcx
0x11119d5cf <+134>: callq  0x11119d622               ; _UIApplicationMainPreparations
0x11119d5d4 <+139>: movq   0x1586ef5(%rip), %rdi     ; UIApp
0x11119d5db <+146>: movq   0x14d2b06(%rip), %rsi     ; "_run"
0x11119d5e2 <+153>: callq  *0x115d000(%rip)          ; (void *)0x0000000114a20940: objc_msgSend
0x11119d5e8 <+159>: movq   0x115d001(%rip), %rbx     ; (void *)0x0000000114a1dcc0: objc_release
0x11119d5ef <+166>: movq   %r15, %rdi
0x11119d5f2 <+169>: callq  *%rbx
0x11119d5f4 <+171>: movq   %r14, %rdi
0x11119d5f7 <+174>: callq  *%rbx
0x11119d5f9 <+176>: xorl   %eax, %eax
0x11119d5fb <+178>: addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x11119d5ff <+182>: popq   %rbx
0x11119d600 <+183>: popq   %r12
0x11119d602 <+185>: popq   %r13
0x11119d604 <+187>: popq   %r14
0x11119d606 <+189>: popq   %r15
0x11119d608 <+191>: popq   %rbp
0x11119d609 <+192>: retq   
0x11119d60a <+193>: leaq   0x157fbff(%rip), %rdi     ; _UIApplicationLinkedOnVersionOnce
0x11119d611 <+200>: leaq   0x1160910(%rip), %rsi     ; __block_literal_global.1491
0x11119d618 <+207>: callq  0x11200edf6               ; symbol stub for: dispatch_once
0x11119d61d <+212>: jmp    0x11119d593               ; <+74>
```

Comment: post the complete crash log

Comment: crash on thread 1:
0 objc_exception_throw
19 UIApplicationMain
20 main(breakpoint here)
21 start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, cancel the searchController

```
[self searchBarCancelButtonClicked:yourSearchBar];
```

or

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

and then dismiss the view controller.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will help.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much! This really help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```